# Geocoding fails in script with Acces violation error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, geocoding, pyscripter

I'm trying to run geocoding in a python script with arcpy. However, I'm always getting an application error:

[image]

I've run the script in PyScripter, ArcMap Python window and Idle, and on several different machines, with the same results. I can manually geocode the data just fine.

Don't know if it makes a difference, but if I run the script a second time without closing the editor. the error is:

[image]

Code:

```
try:
    print("In geocode_facilities...\n")
    address_fields = "Street Street;City Fac_City;Zip Fac_Zip"
    arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding(childcare_table, geocoder, address_fields, geocoded_fc, "STATIC")

except:
     print("\n\tUnexpected error {0}\n\t{1}".format(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1]))
     arcpy.AddError(sys.exc_info()[1])
     ok = False
```

The except clause doesn't get triggered. Straight to access violation error when the script reaches the geocoding line. The first print statement executes, replacing semicolons with commas doesn't change the result. Table to geocode has ~ 750 records. Any clues?

Edit:
I'm using [ESRI documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/geocoding-toolbox/geocode-addresses.htm#C_GUID-9B83ECCC-C4CD-417B-9BF4-CE422C064F84) as a guide. Based on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144828/how-to-geocode-automatically-through-arcpy-without-runtime-error), I put the address fields in a list: `["Street Street;City Fac_City;Zip Fac_Zip"]`. This eliminates the application error, but gives a RunTime error of *Object: Error in executing too*l which the except clause does catch.

Comment: Is it hitting that print statement?

Comment: What do you mean by manually geocoding? If that doesn't mean using the same data with the GeocodeAddresses geoprocessing tool, does that produce the same error?

Comment: Manually geocoding = if I right click the table in ArcCatalog and select Geocode addresses, pick the same address locator, it runs fine. It's only failing when run as a script. And yes, it hits the print statement.

Comment: Have you tried commas instead of semicolons in `address_fields`?

Comment: No change, added replies to original post.

Comment: How big is the table you're geocoding (# of records)?

Comment: See above for edits.